# Add columns to a tibble from a list of names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a situation where I need to add an arbitrary number of columns to a tibble. The column names that I need to add will come from a list.

If it were just one column, it's easy, I would just use `add_column()`.

For example, starting with tibble, **df**, I can add column **c** like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = 3:1)
df <- add_column(df, c = 0)
```

Which yields...

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     3     0
2     2     2     0
3     3     1     0
```

That leads me to believe that if I want to add multiple columns, for example from a list, **new_cols**, I could just map them onto `add_column()` but for some reason, I can't.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = 3:1)

new_cols <- c('d','e','f')

map(new_cols, ~ df <- add_column(df, . = 0))
```

... thinking about this some more of course map() is the wrong idea-- the whole point of map is to generate a list and not side-effects.

I am sure there's an easy one-liner for this, but it escapes me right now.

Comment: Yes, there was an answer from 8 years ago that answers this question, however, the question was phrased somewhat differently, so I decided to not delete this question in case anyone comes across this again (I had missed the existing answers when I looked for it). Also, one of the other answers here discusses using purrr to do this which isn't addressed in the old answers.

Comment: If you specify in this question that you want to add columns from a list of names by `tibble::add_column`, or by other `tidyverse` solution, then this question will no longer be duplicate because you search for a new solution different from an existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
df[new_cols] <- 0

# A tibble: 3 × 5
      a     b     d     e     f
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     0     0     0
2     2     2     0     0     0
3     3     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple, I can't believe I missed it!

Answer (score 1):

If you search for a `purrr` solution like `map`, try `reduce`:

```r
reduce(new_cols, ~ add_column(.x, '{.y}' := 0), .init = df)

# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#       a     b     d     e     f
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     0     0     0
# 2     2     2     0     0     0
# 3     3     1     0     0     0
```

---

You can also inject a named vector or named list of arguments into `add_column()` with the splice operator `!!!`.

```r
new_names <- c('d','e','f')
new_cols <- set_names(rep(0, length(new_names)), new_names)

new_cols
# d e f 
# 0 0 0

add_column(df, !!!new_names)

# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#       a     b     d     e     f
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     0     0     0
# 2     2     2     0     0     0
# 3     3     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, also works! "map()" has a lesser known cousin, "reduce()", that I forgot about!